# how to structure Java code for reuse?

Tags: java, code-reuse

I am looking for something like a compiler directive in C or C++ or something like it for Java. Why you ask?

I have a body of Java code, it used to be for one project. Then a second project, code was based on the first project. So a copy of the first one with many changes. Same structure though as far as package names and contents, etc. But the class internal were different.

Now there is a third project, something like the first and the second one mixed together.

How do I structure the code to have one code base/ git repo that contains all three projects code? And how do I determine what code path is to be run? at runtime is it project 1 or project 2 or project three? Compiler directives are used for C/C++. Java?

Comment: Use `if(flag)` instead of `#ifdef`

Answer (score 2):

There are no compiler directives (`ifdef`) in Java.

Abstract what is common and create a single library (or multiple libraries if needed) that provides the base functionality that is being reused.  Then refactor all the projects to use (i.e. extend or compose) classes from the library.  This is what OO programming is all about.

Comment: I understand the Abstract and the fact that is no ifdef in Java... To tell the code what application is being run, just use a command line argument? Any more elegant way?

Comment: No, I meant "abstract" as a verb.  Look at how the different applications are using the code and figure out what is common. Then write a set of classes that captures that common base functionality, and extend it as needed for each project.

Comment: You don't need `#ifdef` in Java most of the time as using `if(flag)` can be just as efficient in Java.

Answer (score 0):

I am using ANT Build Script to build my java project. I've a build.properties that contains various values a variable can have. My build.xml implements various specific build targets like debug, release, test. Using different build targets for ant (ant debug, ant release), I can have various versions of jar using same code base. Works nicely for build time variables based on ant targets.

**build.properties**

```
# Build Parameters
# Turn On of Off debugging
config.debug_true=true
config.debug_false=false
```

**Config.java**
Define this java class somewhere in your project. I did in /config folder under project directory.

```
package com.stackoverflow.ajitk;

public class Config {

   // Build for DEBUG or RELEASE
   public final static boolean DEBUG = @CONFIG.DEBUG@;
}
```

**build.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="ABC" default="release">
    <property file="build.properties" />

...

  <macrodef name="copy-release-parameters">
      <sequential>
    <property name="config-target-path" value="gen/com/stackoverflow/ajitk"/>
    <!-- Copy the configuration file, replacing tokens in the file. -->
    <copy file="config/Config.java" todir="${config-target-path}"
    overwrite="true" encoding="utf-8">
    <filterset>
        <filter token="CONFIG.DEBUG" value="${config.debug_false}"/>
        <--... add more variables as needed by your project ... -->
    </filterset>
    </copy>
      </sequential>
  </macrodef>

...

<-- the above macro should be used in your release/debug target -->

...

</project>
```

Comment: Let me know if you face any issues using this approach...